# Hazelcast Cache - Printing too many logs ( Ignoring join check from [10.10.10.10]:5702, because this node is not master...)

Tags: java, caching, jboss, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast Cache for my application.
I have two nodes of Jboss on two different Machines.
Each nodes have two deployments.
Each deployment file has their own hazelcast cache.

I want to cluster between two nodes for each application and below is my configurations,

```
Config config = new Config();
config.setClusterName("uniqueClusterName");
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("10.100.101.82,10.100.101.83").setEnabled(true);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
manager = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

My above configuration is working fine and both the nodes are making cluster on each application.

But I have found below logs, and these logs are printing continuously

```
INFO  [com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp] (hz.cocky_jackson.priority-generic-operation.thread-0) [10.100.101.82]:5702 [losce_qa] [4.1] Ignoring join check from [10.100.101.83]:5702, because this node is not master...
INFO  [com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp] (hz.hungry_hofstadter.priority-generic-operation.thread-0) [10.100.101.82]:5701 [losce_qa] [4.1] Ignoring join check from [10.100.101.83]:5702, because this node is not master...
INFO  [com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp] (hz.cocky_jackson.generic-operation.thread-1) [10.100.101.82]:5702 [losce_qa] [4.1] Ignoring join check from [10.100.101.83]:5702, because this node is not master...
```

Any work around? How to avoid these logs or I'm doing something wrong here?

TIA

Comment: Do you mean you wish two separate Hazelcast clusters running on the same hardware ?

Comment: As asked by Neil, please provide more information about your deployment. And what the IP addresses `10.100.101.82` and `10.100.101.83` are.

Comment: @NeilStevenson  Yes, I have two different machines 10.100.101.82 and 10.100.101.83 and on both the machines, I have two separate deployment (ear). On each deployment, I have created the hazelcast cluster cache which means,
my **Deployment1-ear** on 82 and 83 will make cluster => with unique cluster name
&
my **Deployment2-ear** on 82 and 83 will make cluster => with unique cluster name

Comment: @RafałLeszko  10.100.101.82 and 10.100.101.83 are my servers IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Two clusters sharing the same hardware isn't ideal, as they contend for machine resources.

But if you do, you don't want them clashing, which is what will happen with the default port allocation. The default being to try to listen on port 5701, if this is busy try 5702 and so on. And to try to find other cluster members assuming they are on 5701 also.

To make it work:

(1) Give them unique names, as you've done

```
config.setClusterName("uniqueClusterName");
```

&

```
config.setClusterName("uniqueClusterName2");
```

As they have different cluster names, members from one cluster won't be able to
join the other. This won't stop them trying, which is causing unwanted log messages.

(2) Assign predictable ports

Try

```
config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(6701);
```

&

```
config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(7701);
```

They will both try to find ports starting from different offsets, which will allow for predictability.

Without this, both clusters will try to use the default 5701 as the first port, and whichever cluster starts first will success.

With this, the first cluster's member will try and should succeed to get 6701. The second cluster's member will try and should succeed to get 7701.

(3) Specify addresses and ports for connectivity attempts

Try

```
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig()
.addMember("10.100.101.82:6701,10.100.101.83:6701")
```

and

```
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig()
.addMember("10.100.101.82:7701,10.100.101.83:7701")
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I have configured above in my application and it is working fine now. No extra logs is printing. :)